# Is there a way to uncap the simulation runtime?

Tags: vivado

Vivado has a simulation runtime setting that allows me to set the limit for how long a simulation will run. Is there a way to set the simulation runtime to unlimited? IE the simulation runs until the $stop command is reached in the testbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From AMD docs [here](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/2021.2-English/ug900-vivado-logic-simulation/export_simulation), the default behavior (if no runtime parameter is specified) is that the simulation runs until the simulation finds a stop command:

```
[-runtime]  
Run simulation for this time.

Default: full simulation run or until a logical break or finish condition
```